# How to overcome this issue when i run the command "npm install"

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web

its shows this error:
up to date, audited 1464 packages in 8s

247 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\BEYOND\OneDrive\Desktop\react-portfolio-tutorial-1-main_1 (3)\react-portfolio-website-1>

this is what did i try:

PS C:\Users\BEYOND\OneDrive\Desktop\react-portfolio-tutorial-1-main_1 (3)\react-portfolio-website-1> npm install

Answer (score 0):

try
rm -r .\node_modules
rm -r .\package-lock.json
then
npm i

Comment: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
added 512 packages, changed 42 packages, and audited 1464 packages in 55s

247 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.